# Trying to get specific attribute in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am tring to get the attribute `type="radio"` but I'm not sure how to in the selenium webdriver. 
I tried by using

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("userStatusEnable")).getAttribute("type").equals("radio"))
```

and also by changing the id to x-auto-210

```
<div id="userStatusEnable" class="x-form-check-wrap x-form-field x-component " role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
<input id="x-auto-210" class=" x-form-radio" type="radio" name="gxt.RadioGroup.5" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 4px;" tabindex="0" value="enabled" aria-describedby="x-auto-190" checked="">
<label class="x-form-cb-label" for="x-auto-210" htmlfor="x-auto-210" style="position: relative; left: 1px; top: 3px;">Enable</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Find the element with `type="radio"`, or verify an element found with another selector has `type="radio"`?

Comment: Yea im trying to verify that the ID is of type radio. So i have to confirm that there are 2 radio buttons present on the page i am working with right now but im not sure how to get the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use `findElements()` and an xpath selector to find `input` tags with a `type="radio"`:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']")).size() == 2)
```

Comment: seems that OP needs to be sure that there are two radios of specific ID, then it would be: `if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='x-auto-210'][@type='radio']")).size() == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you want to find all input elements with the id `x-auto-210` and the type `radio`. You can do that with the following XPath:

```
"//input[@id='x-auto-210' and @type='radio']"
```

I've added an explanation of what the XPath expression is doing

1. The `//` says we want to search all element
2. The `input` means we are only interested in input elements
3. The `[]` contains the conditions we want the input to match (namely, that the id is `x-auto-210` and the type is `radio`)

If you use this expression in conjunction with findElements in selenium, you should be able to find the desired elements

```
if (driver.findElements(By.XPath("//input[@id='x-auto-210' and @type='radio']")).size() == 2) {
    //Do stuff
}
```